# Cleaner way of choosing between start and restart

Tags: ansible, systemd

I have ansible configuration for deploying locally built daemons to a series of target machines, these daemons have associated systemd service files to control them.

What I want to happen is:

1. If daemon or unit file is changed then restart service
2. If daemon is unchanged then just start service (which may count as 'unchanged', because it's probably already running)

I'm doing this in a few places so I have a commonly repeating pattern that looks like:

```
- name: Populate the daemon
  copy:
    src: "local_build/mydaemon"
    dest: "/usr/bin/mydaemon"
    mode: 0775
  register: daemon_bin

- name: Populate the service
  template:
    src: "Daemon.service"
    dest: "/etc/systemd/system/mydaemon.service"
  register: daemon_service

- name: Enable and restart
  systemd:
    state: restarted
    daemon_reload: yes
    enabled: yes
    name: "mydaemon.service"
  when: (daemon_bin.changed or daemon_service.changed)

- name: Enable and start
  systemd:
    state: started
    enabled: yes
    name: "mydaemon.service"
  when: not (daemon_bin.changed or daemon_service.changed)
```

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this? It feels like it might be a common problem. Or is my approach somehow wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [notify and handlers](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html).

Comment: Handlers won't work in the 'either x or y' case though. If I had a handler for 'restarted' I'd still have to have a normal task for 'started' and they both might end up running

Comment: Changes notify the handler for 'restarted'. Force execution of the handlers (meta: flush_handlers). Then normal task for 'started'. The service should be (re)started only once.